# Does the below code really free memory in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c

Here is the code:

```
int main()
{   
   char str[] = {'a','b','c',' ','d','e',' ',' ','f',' ',' ',' ','g','h','i',' ',' ',' ',' ','j','k'};
   cout << "Len = " << strlen(str) << endl;

   char* cstr = new char[strlen(str)];
   strcpy(cstr, str); 

   cstr[5] = '\0';

   cout << "Len= " << strlen(cstr) << endl;

   return 0;
}

//---------------
Result console:
Len = 21                                                                                                                                                                        
Len= 5
```

As you see the Len of cstr changed. It mean that remain memory area of cstr is free. Is it right?

Comment: `new char[strlen(str)];` should be `new char[strlen(str)+1];` to allow for the null character

Comment: What is your concept of 'empty'? All you actually do is replace one single character in the allocated memory by a nil byte. Also mind you're allocating to little memory as pointed out by Ed Heal.

Comment: I don't really agree with people negativating this question. This guy's trying to understand the concepts and people are not estimulating him to do that. I think the problem are people who asks for homework done.

Comment: @Paulo I aggree, there are too many people on stack now that downvote for whatever reason and do not even bother to explain why.

Comment: The very first `strlen` call is undefined behaviour. str is not a nul-terminated string.

Comment: Surely, but there is plenty of excellent literature on these beginner's topics. Also, there is so few information given in his question that each and every single answer can only be a guess, imho.

Comment: I think we should warn him here at the comments what he should do, instead of down voting him. OR, we could down vote him and explain the reason as @Slava said.

Comment: the string that `cstr` holds is now 5 chars long, but the memory allocated of `cstr` isn't. That block was allocated, and is never freed by you (it will probably be deallocated when your program terminates though). for that, you need to `delete` the variable

Comment: Not delete[] but delete, that was not allocated using the array allocator. Yes, the memory is released at program termination by standard.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No. All strlen() does is look for the first null character ('\0') in the string. It doesn't free memory. It doesn't even care if the memory it examines is properly allocated. It will happily walk past the end of allocated memory in search of a null character if none is found starting from the pointer you give it.

Comment: Looks like he did not think that `strlen()` releases memory, but `cstr[5] = '\0';`

Comment: Thanks everybody, I understand memory in C/C++ more. Also thanks John Bode and Pravar Jawalekar for your answer

Answer (score 7):

The code is broken from the starts. `str` is not a nul-terminated string, and as such can't be used with functions expecting those strings, such as `strlen` or `strcpy`.

Answer (score 5):

> As you see the Len of cstr changed. It mean that remain memory area of
>   cstr is free. Is it right?

No. It's not. You allocated memory for array on heap and then inserted `\0` at place between array. Because of this, `strlen` is reporting length of array equals to 5 (because it computes length of char array by looking \0 character) but memory past that index still exists on heap. To free memory, You need to call `delete [] cstr`.

Answer (score 4):

No. `new` just allocates a chunk of memory of the size you specified. The only way to release it is to call `delete` on it.

`strlen` is a function that parses memory from a starting address and counts the number of non NUL bytes, such a thing is called a C-string.

Putting a NUL byte somewhere in memory is no different from putting any other value for the memory management.

Answer (score 4):

> As you see the Len of cstr changed. It mean that remain memory area of cstr is free. Is it right?

No.  `strlen` only returns the length of the string stored within the array, not the size of the array itself.  The length of the string may be anywhere from 0 to `strlen(str)` - 1, but the size of `cstr` is always going to be `strlen(str)`.

The size of the array does not change just because you stored a smaller string to it, any more than a glass gets smaller if you only fill it half way.  The *only* way to release the memory pointed to by `cstr` is to use the `delete` operator.

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not mean that *remain memory area of str is free*.

---

`strlen(cstr)` calculates the length of the string upto a point when a `NUL` `\0` character is encountered.

In the beginning you allocated a char array of length `22` char. Replacing a `char` in between with a `NUL` `\0` is only going to make `strlen` believe that the string is upto `5` char long. It will not free the other `17` char that were allocated for the local char array after that replaced char.

The memory for `char` array `str` will get get unallocated once the function `main()` exits (since it is a local array).

Comment: "*allocated a char array of length 22 char*" - more like 22+*RandomNumber*, since `str` is not null-terminated, thus `strlen(str)` is undefined behavior. Also, your answer starts out talking about behavior related to `cstr` but then ends with talking about behavior related to `str` instead.  Your answer is misleading as worded.  `cstr` is indeed leaked, as it is allocated on the heap and not freed before `main()` exits. Only `str` is freed when it goes out of scope.